Calculating the effect of the sensor's viewing angle on the point spread function from a geometric perspective
I apologize in advance for the way I describe my problem, but I have no background in mathematics, although the problem I try to solve involves geometry.
I have two satellite images, one captured an image for an area from a near-nadir (NN) position and the other from an off-nadid (ON) viewing angle (VA). Both images captures the same area, but from different VA, at the same time. My task is to downscale both satellite images (i.e., increase their spatial resolution) while accounting for the point spread function (PSF) and measure the impact of the VA on the PSF from a geometric perspective. Let me explain.
If I project a viewing cone (the sensor) from nadir the footprint (support) is circular and has minimum area (given fixed viewing height).
If I project the same viewing cone (the sensor) at an angle, off-nadir, then the support is an ellipse and it has a larger area.
The greater the angle off-nadir, the more pronounced the ellipse and the larger the area.
The areal increase can be calculated from geometry. That is, it is known.
I am interesting to test if the predicted increase in the PSF is equal to this known geometric effect.
I downscaled the satellite images and I found that the PSF at the NN is $1$ and at the ON is $1.3$ (measured in pixels). These values are the predicted values. How can I calculate the theoretical PSF at the ON VA?
The simplest solution I could think of is this:
For a given off-nadir angle $\theta$, the relationship between the circular near-nadir support and the elliptical off-nadir footprin can be expressed using the ellipse's major axis. If the nadir PSF width is $d$ ($1$ in my case), the off-nadir PSF width, $\kappa$, can be approximated by:
$$\kappa= \frac{d}{\cos(\theta)}.$$
Assuming that the sensor's VA is $40^\circ$, then:
$$\kappa= \frac{d}{\cos(\theta)} \implies \frac{1}{0.766} = 1.305 \, \text{pixels}$$ (my predicted PSF was $1.3$).
If the VA is $> 40^\circ$, then of course the $\kappa$ becomes larger.
Is this the correct approach/equation to my problem?
